# Create a DOM Event from a jQuery Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I am using a 3rd party library that triggers a jQuery event and I am using another 3rd party library that listens for DOM events.

I need to connect those two! I was thinking to do something like this:

```
$(el).on('change', function (e) {
    if (e.originalEvent) return; // already a DOM event
    el.dispatchEvent(e.makeDOMEvent());
});
```

Obviously jQuery doesn't have a `makeDOMEvent()` function... but is there something equivalent?

Comment: add both of the scripts on the page No ?

Comment: Why do you need a separate API, other than jQuery, for DOM Events?

Comment: I am using a third party library that uses DOM Events, that's all. It is not so much a matter of needing it, but that is what I have to work with.

Comment: No if you look closer, if I find a DOM Event in `originalEvent`, I return immediately and skip trying to dispatch the event. My jQuery library is using `trigger()` to dispatch the event.

Comment: Why not use native DOM events everywhere? Your use of `trigger()` implies you are creating custom events with jQuery. Simply create custom DOM events and use DOM events everywhere. jQuery's `on()` method will still capture them all.

Comment: Once again, my third party library is the one using `trigger()`, not me.

Comment: Oh my bad, I thought jQuery `trigger()` would itself call `EventTarget.dispatchEvent`, but they actually only call `EventTarget.onEvent` if set, and dispatch ClickEvents, not any other Event... Beware they officially refused to implement this behavior in the fear of infinite loops caused by bubbling events: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2476

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question here because I haven't seen any official way to do it.

Basically I just use plain old Javascript to create a new event:

```
$(el).on('change', function (e) {
    if (e.originalEvent) return; // already a DOM event
    el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
    }));
});
```

This loses any data from the jQuery event.

Comment: You might want to stopImmediatePropagation this triggered event: in case you have some other jQuery listening to it, it will fire twice. And if you absolutely need your jQuery event, then you could attach it to the DOM Event: `var evt = new Event([...]); evt.jQueryEvent = e; el.dipatchEvent(evt);` And then retrieve it in `e.originalEvent.jQueryEvent`.